# coded ui can't find components in chrome while playing back recordings from IE

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, coded-ui-tests

I want to test reactJS App with coded UI and play it back with Chrome browser. I'm recording my actions on IE, I have all selenium components and browser drivers installed, my chrome version is latest(tried older versions too). Scenario of my test is to type both login and password, log in then log out. So when i run my test on IE everything works perfectly. But if i run it on Chrome it types everything logs in, so when its on the main page with loads of components it wouldn't find log out button, saying it couldn't find controls with given info(tags, ids, classes). But when i inspect element with the info from test it matches perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind folks, Solved the issue. Turns out Chrome doesn't wait for all components to load unlike IE. So as long as it clicked on login button it was going to search for that component not even waiting for page to load. So I just set some conditions telling to wait until everything loaded then try to look for components.

Comment: Hi Nurik,
thank you for providing a answer to your question. As your answer is the correct one for you, you should mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but it tells me that i need some time to mark my own answer as a correct one.